# Нужно ли всё ещё добавлять префиксы для бразуеров?

Tags: css, css3, браузер, кроссбраузерность

Увидел в книге по CSS 2015 года, что префиксы вроде -webkit- и -ms- желательно юзать, и что в будущем префиксы должны убрать, чтобы не нужно было новые строчки писать. Свежей инфы нет. Нужно ли их ещё добавлять, или это пофиксили?

Comment: Для некоторых св-в да, для некоторых нет)

Comment: Видел на каком-то сайте скрипт, просто добавляешь js файл и префиксы не надо ставить. Не подскажете?

Answer (score 1):

Ну как минимум что бы самому их не писать, можно в галпе подключить автопрефиксер

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

gulp.task('default', () =>
    gulp.src('src/app.css')
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
);
```

Comment: ну вы хотя бы приложите код, как подключать и настраивать автопрефиксер в галпе. Иначе на ответ не тянет